# Fatal error on Framework

Tags: error, magento2.2

I moved to new server and ready to install Magento but I getting this error
please help!

> Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException:
>   The file
>   "/home/xxxx/public_html/generated/code/Symfony/Component/Console/Question/QuestionFactory.php"
>   cannot be deleted
>   Warning!unlink(/home/xxxx/public_html/generated/code/Symfony/Component/Console/Question/QuestionFactory.php):
>   Permission denied in
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:382
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(405):
>   Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteFile('/home/xxxx/...')
>    #1 /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(403):
>   Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/home/xxxx/...')
>    #2 /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(403):
>   Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/home/xxxx/...')
>    #3 /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(403):
>   Magento\Framework\File in
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php
>   on line 382

new

Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/home/xxxx/public_html/var/page_cache" is not writable in /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209 Stack trace: #0 /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/hom...') #1 /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/home/xxxx/...') #2 /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #3 /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) #4 /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(158): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true) #5 /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framewor in /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php on line 209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please give 777 permission to generated and var folder

remove generated folder and var/cahe var/di and var/page_cache and var/view_processed and try it –

Comment: yes already give 777, but cant

Comment: -> remove generated  folder and var/cahe var/di and var/page_cache and var/view_processed and try it

Comment: i updated in the post please see

Comment: is ok now~thank you!

Comment: pemission issue if solve then like it